# Django cursor.executemany what's the preferred batch size for each "executemany"

Tags: python, mysql, django, executemany

I use the following code to do bulk insert with extended "insert into".

```
    cursor = connections['default'].cursor()

    sql = "INSERT INTO %s (%s) VALUES ([xxx], [xxx], ...) "

    step = 1000
    for l in range(0, len(values), step):
        s_values = values[l:l+step]
        cursor.executemany(sql, s_values)
```

My question here is if I have a lot of rows to insert, for example, 100, 000:

should I insert in one query.

or call multiple executemany with fixed step, such as 1000.

I read some articles, it is suggest to use 100.

I test my code with 100, 000 records to insert.

One executemany is faster than multiple.

I am not sure what should I do. Not sure whether I miss understood something here.

Please help to comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) documentation helps elaborate on that:

> In most cases, the executemany() method iterates through the sequence of parameters, each time passing the current parameters to the the execute() method.

> An optimization is applied for inserts: The data values given by the parameter sequences are batched using multiple-row syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I understand this. but just should I throw all data into one executemany()? should I split the data into small chunk incase of network package size limit or more data block MySQL with longer time?

Comment: Yes, executemany() will find the optimal method of handling the quantity of data you give it in a semi-dynamic fashion.  As long as the response of the request is within the packet limit you shouldn't have an issue and (barring a few exceptions) it should be faster than a home remedy of timed-batch executions, imho.

Comment: Thank you @Xinthral. This is also what I see. Then I will give all the data to extecutemany. I can increase the message packet size of MySQL if I hit the limit.